# ARCore: How to display saved images from device on a surface

Tags: java, android, image, mobile, arcore

I am a newbie in AR. I was wondering if there is a way where you can display picture that you saved on a phone to a surface using ARCore for android. Like I was able to use the Sceneform example with a precoded image but now I would like to show a photo from my picture folder to a surface. I read about texture but I am not sure how that works either.
Thank you for your tips.

**EDIT**:
so I create a class where the user can select an image from there I am saving through Uri

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == this.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        return;
    }
    if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
        if (data != null) {
            contentURI = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), contentURI);
                String path = saveImage(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(imageSelector.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //set the image selected to bitmap so that imageView can display it
                imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelloSceneformActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("imageUri", contentURI.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
```

And from the ARclass side I called the intent and parse it as follow

```
//start the intent for the image chosen from the library
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    Uri myUri = Uri.parse(extras.getString("imageUri"));

    // When you build a Renderable, Sceneform loads its resources in the background while returning
    // a CompletableFuture. Call thenAccept(), handle(), or check isDone() before calling get().
    ModelRenderable.builder()
            .setSource(this, myUri)
            .build()
            .thenAccept(renderable -> andyRenderable = renderable)
            .exceptionally(
                    throwable -> {
                        Toast toast =
                                Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load andy renderable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                        toast.show();
                        return null;
                    });
```

I am able to select the picture but program crashes and I get this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.ar.sceneform.samples.hellosceneform/com.google.ar.sceneform.samples.hellosceneform.HelloSceneformActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to parse url: 'content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F460/ORIGINAL/NONE/1926270799'

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to parse url: 'content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F460/ORIGINAL/NONE/1926270799'
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.utilities.LoadHelper.remoteUriToInputStreamCreator(Unknown Source:56)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.utilities.LoadHelper.fromUri(Unknown Source:40)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.Renderable$Builder.build(Renderable.java:343)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.ModelRenderable$Builder.build(ModelRenderable.java:44)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.samples.hellosceneform.HelloSceneformActivity.onCreate(HelloSceneformActivity.java:92)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
```

Comment: You can detect a ground plane, tap it and instantiate a quad with the image and right orientation.. If you have written any code I can help you more

Comment: @RandomStranger this is what I have

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know you were working in java.. I hope someone else might help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/79 you can't load from custom URIs at the moment:

> in 1.0 we interpret all file:// uris as being relative to the assets folder which is why we fail to load from external storage. Consequently, in order to load a Texture from a Uri, you'll need to either put in in the assets folder (i.e. bundled into your apk), or host it online where it's available via an http:// scheme.

This implies only http:// and file:// URIs are supported at the moment and the latter can only be relative to the assets folder. That is confirmed in malik-at-work's answer on https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/64:

> The URI based file loading isn't looking at external storage. Right now it's only looking for application assets using file:// and remote uris starting with http://

EDIT: A workaround I'd suggest is using the [ViewRenderable](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/rendering/ViewRenderable) in combination with a layout with a single ImageView inside. The ViewRenderable can create 2D-Layouts in the Scene, you just have to set your image into the ImageView like you would in a usual Android-App and position / rotate the resulting object to your liking. You can find an example-usage of the ViewRenderable in the [solarsystem-Sceneform-example](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/tree/master/solarsystem), the sliders for the speeds are realized with it.

EDIT 2:
It seems that this is fixed in Sceneform 1.4 since the first mentioned issue has now been closed.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to find a way around it. I played the context and CallableBitmapStream on setSource which supports it.

Comment: Could you elaborate further, maybe give a code example? I can't find any `CallableBitmapStream` online but I'd like to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the image as a List of Uri

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
Button Gallery, AR;
private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
Uri imageUri;
ImageView imageview;
private ArFragment arFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Gallery = findViewById(R.id.select);
    AR = findViewById(R.id.ar);
    imageview = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    AR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity.class);
            MainActivity2.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });

    Gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openGallery();
        }
    });


}
private void openGallery() {
    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        imageUri = data.getData();
        imageview.setImageURI(imageUri);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        arFragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
        assert arFragment != null;
        arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener((hitResult, plane, motionEvent) - > {
            Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
            createViewRenderable(hitResult.createAnchor());
        });

    }

}
private void addModeltoScene(Anchor anchor, ModelRenderable modelRenderable) {
    AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
    TransformableNode transformableNode = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
    transformableNode.setParent(anchorNode);
    transformableNode.setRenderable(modelRenderable);
    arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(anchorNode);
    transformableNode.select();
}
private void createViewRenderable(Anchor anchor) {
    ViewRenderable
        .builder()
        .setView(this, R.layout.text)
        .build()
        .thenAccept(viewRenderable - > {
            addtoScene(viewRenderable, anchor);
        });
}
private void addtoScene(ViewRenderable viewRenderable, Anchor anchor) {
    AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
    anchorNode.setRenderable(viewRenderable);
    arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(anchorNode);
    View view = viewRenderable.getView();
    ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    List < Uri > images = new ArrayList < > ();
    images.add(imageUri);
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(images);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


}

class Adapter extends PagerAdapter {
    List < Uri > images;
    Adapter(List < Uri > images) {
        this.images = images;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
}
}
```

I have written an article on the same. Kindly check it out. It is about displaying 2D images from your gallery in AR form.
https://medium.com/@deveshbhatla952/displaying-2-d-images-from-external-storage-in-ar-form-using-google-sceneform-2baae45f1a42
I have tried it and it works perfectly.